# Is there a way to share Snowflake temp tables between different connection instances?

Tags: session, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, temp-tables

In the Snowflake database I am creating a temporary table. I want to connect another tool (e.g. Tableau) to that temporary table. Is there a way to do this?

I can't create transient or permanent tables.
Creating local copy of temporary table is also impossible because of the size limitations.

Comment: No - temporary tables are scoped to a specific session and a session is scoped to a single login from a single user. If you have a genuine business need to create tables then you should be give access to create transient/permanent tables - otherwise it sounds like you are trying to get round your company's governance controls